# Configuring pfSENSE

Tags: networking, pfsense

I am quite new to pfSENSE, andI want to configure 4 diffrent subnets in pfSENSE

Any idea, how I can do this ?

Looking forward to hearing from you - best regards,

Axel

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @yass - Help, right now I have a basic problem: I have set up a WAN connection which is DHCP, and a static LAN - I can connect via the static LAN from a laptop to pfsense using the web console. But on the laptop I can not get aninternet connection, neither do the 2 PC's that are connected.

Answer (score 0):

If your switch is capable of 802.1q vlan tagging, then create 4 vlans in pfsense. Each vlan having its own subnet and dhcp server pool. Pfsense will take care of the routing for you, but you may need to add firewall rules defending on your access requirements. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

you have two options.

1. (without VLANS) add more physical interfaces to the PFsense installation. this option really depends on what PFsense is running on.i.e PCI/PCI-e cards. i personally wouldn't recommend USB adapters.
2. (with VLANS) add Virtual interfaces to the parent network adapter in PFsense. you need to have a VLAN capable switch to accomplish this. additionally it needs to support 802.1q trunking. and be configured for it, and the access ports mapped to the VLANs you want them to reside in.